# Amazon SWF: Activity type is not supported by the Activity worker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

My workflow (say WorkFlow A) has got a few activities registered(say ActivityA, etc)

I am getting the following error when my workflow exectutes:

```
    com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.ActivityTaskFailedException: Activity type "{Name: "AcitivityA", Version: 1.0}" is not supported by the ActivityWorker. 

Possible cause is activity type version change without changing task list name. Activity types registered with the worker are: [{Name: "WorkflowB" for activityId="1" of activityType={Name: "ActivityA", Version: 1.0}
```

Not sure whey "WorkflowB" is coming up in the error. 
What is the possible reason of such an error? 
Any inputs are appreciated. I am new to SWF.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

going to guess that your worker is using a different task list. 
Also going to guess that in this context WorkflowB in the error message is the tasklist, not the actual workflow.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dev-task-lists.html

double check the task lists that you are using when building the workers.
also, please note that once you've registered an activity, you cannot change the parameters that you're using. It's possible that you've registered the activity with a default task list first and after that you've changed the tasklist in the code. this will not work. SWF will preserve the old default task list for that activity version